# Adding an image in a PHP Plugin for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having issues trying to add an image before the content on my WordPress website. The image error icon keeps popping up after I try the code below. The image itself is in the plugin folder. Hope you can help, and thanks for taking a peek at my post!

**Original code:**

```php
<?php

function before_after($content) {
    $beforecontent = '<img src="stayhealthylogo.jpg" />';
    $aftercontent = '<h2>Wordpress</h2>';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'before_after');

?>
```

**Edit with updated code**, I am now getting a *syntax error*, possibly has to do with the quotes? Can someone help me with this?

**Updated code:**

```php
<?php

function before_after($content) {
    $beforecontent = '<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'stayhealthylogo.jpg'; ?>">';
    $aftercontent = '<h6>WordPress</h6>';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'before_after');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are seeing is the broken image icon, then the `src` attribute of your `img` element is incorrect. You'll need to make sure the full path to your image matches the image location on your server.

This question/answer seems related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60230/how-to-call-images-from-your-plugins-image-folder

UPDATE:
This should fix your syntax error:

```php
<?php

function before_after($content) {
    $beforecontent = '<img src="' . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'stayhealthylogo.jpg">';
    $aftercontent = '<h6>WordPress</h6>';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'before_after');

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me zeterain. I am still getting an error when trying to use the syntax recommended in that article. Can you see what I am doing incorrectly? I believe it is a syntax error with the quotes, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show you how to fix that syntax error.